# Download a file and keeping the original name

Tags: c#, .net, download

After I downloaded a file using this code:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
    fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);

    Response.Clear();

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + item.filename);

    Response.BinaryWrite(memStream.ToArray());
    Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Close();
    Response.End();
}
```

The code works very well, but once I open the docx file after the download it loses its original name and I get the message "the file is corrupt and cannot be opened". this only happened to me with the doc & docx files, I tried for xlsx, jpg, pdf, and it worked very well .

Does this have a relation with my code or is it something else?

Comment: Your ContentType is not set properly, try using this ```Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";```

Comment: What is the filename you use? What is the extension? The extension might identify the file as a template. For example, when the extension is xltx or xlt, the file is an Excel template. And when opening the file, Excel will create a new document as a copy. The same is true for dot and dotx extensions for Word

Comment: So what is it? Are you asked to save the file under a new name or do you get a message "the file is corrupt and cannot be opened"?

Comment: I have two things, the first is that I get the message "the file is corrupt and cannot be opened", plus the file doesn't keep its original name after opening it. I will have to give it a new name and save it. all of this happens right after I download the file successfully with its original name.

Comment: Can you provide an example of such a file and what name it uses?

Comment: For example, I download the file " wordDocument.docx " and when I open it it will have no name & the message "the file is corrupt and cannot be opened" get displayed but I will still be able to skip the message and see the content of the file, then when I will close the file I get the demand to save it like it never existed.

Comment: Remove one of either `BinaryWrite` or `TransmitFile`. You can't have both

Comment: Thank you for your help I deleted BinaryWrite and I have no more of the problems

Answer (score 0):

I guess your filename has an extension like `dotx` or `dot`.

The "t" stands for "Template". The default action for "template" type documents in Microsoft Office is to create a new document from a copy of the template.

Look at the different look of Word document and Word template:

[image]

So, if you want the user to download a document and not a template, create a document from the template and send the document to the user with a docx extension.

Comment: no, it's a doc and docx extension, I tried with other types of files (excel, pdf, jpg, ) and I had no problem, it's only in word files. + when I open the file it displays the message: "the file is corrupt and cannot be opened"